# Changing Wordpress Address URL disaster

Tags: url-rewriting

I made a mistake and changed the URL under settings -> General. After this Wordpress locked me out. I first added in the wp-congif.php file:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

This appeared to have fixed the issue but only if I was logged into Wordpress. Users could not enter to the website and they have a forbidden message. My URL to visit my test site would redirect me always to my homepage, etc.

I also resetted the htcaccess file but nothing seems to do the trick. I finally uploaded a full backup of my site and the problem is still there, nothing works and the site is completely broken. Any ideas?

My current htaccess file looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /guiacentros/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /guiacentros/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Do you have shell access to run WP CLI commands? When you say they receive a forbidden message, can you be more specific? Editing your question with a screenshots or quotes/snippets will help

Comment: The get "Forbidden – You don’t have permission to access ‘/’ on this server."

Comment: that sounds more like an Apache response than a WordPress response, check the /readme.html file if it loads ( if it doesnt then this is not a WP issue ), and the file/folder permissions

Comment: It's probably a problem with the htaccess file right?

Comment: What's the location of this `.htaccess` file? is it in your web root directory or is it in `/guiacentros/` directory?

Comment: The /guiacentros/ directory.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by adding a htaccess file to the root directory with this information:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_subdir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_subdir/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ my_subdir/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

The main issues was Wordpress being installed in a subdirectory, so the root URL was "example.com/subdirectory" instead of "example.com". This htaccess comfiguration does redirect users properly.

Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the wp_options table and check the values for `siteurl` and `home` - these are the values that would have been changed when you submitted the form, so you could change them back directly there.  This may not be it but it's worth trying.

Comment: Is it ok to change this in http://example.com/wp-admin/options.php? I'm not sure how to access the wp_options.

Comment: Sorry - I meant in your database - no, you shouldn't edit that file!  Do you have access?  I'm also assuming now you're back into the admin that you've tried just re-editing the URL under Settings -> General ?

Comment: I've re-uploaded an entire backup so the url should be valid, besides since I'm not locked from the site the Wordpress URL should be ok? I think I have to access the wp_config and I'm just not sure how...I just have the ftp details and wp log in details.

Comment: @Sergi never modify WordPress core files under `wp-admin` or `wp-includes`, if you do, we can't diagnose the problem, and any solutions you come across may no longer apply

Comment: I mean actually putting /options.php in the url, I have changed the home url there but as soon as I refresh the site any change is reverted. I'm now downloading phpMyAdmin so I can look at the wp_config file. But I have reuploaded the whole site with a backup...So any changes I could have made done there were reverted.